# Give the Maclaurin series for $f(x)=(3+e^{-x})^2$ and find values of $x$ for which this series converges.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Given is:

$f(x)=(3+e^{-x})^2$

so I write:

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$$

$$e^{-x}x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$$

$$f(x)=\left(3+1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots\right)^2$$

How do I put $f$($x$) in $\sum$ form?

Comment: Hint: Expand the square first. Apply known series later.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$\mathrm{f}(x) = \left(3+\mathrm{e}^{-x}\right)^2 \equiv 9 +6\,\mathrm{e}^{-x}+\mathrm{e}^{-2x}$$

The series are then:

$$9 + 6\left(\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} (-1)^r\frac{x^r}{r!}\right)+\left(\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}(-2)^s\frac{x^s}{s!}\right)$$

$$= 9 + \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\left[6(-1)^t + (-2)^t\right]\frac{x^t}{t!}$$

Comment: Why $\frac{x^r}{r!}$ equals 1?

Comment: Why do you think it does? If $r=0$ then $\displaystyle{\frac{x^r}{r!}=\frac{x^0}{0!} =\frac{1}{1} = 1}$. **However**, if $r>0$ then this is not true.